# Facebook warpdrive build - D Programming language

Tags: c++, facebook, c-preprocessor, d

Of late, facebook opensourced warp, **C**/C++ preprocessor.
https://github.com/facebook/warp

I'm trying to build it using dmd and stuck with some build errors.
I downloaded dmd.2.065.0.zip for dmd compiler - dmd2/linux/bin64/dmd
I also see a bunch of libraries, for example libphobos2.a

Then when I build warp, I see some errors from ld, that keep complaining that phobos2.a could not be found. I exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the dir where this library is stored but no luck.

I compiled in verbose mode, and it doesn't give more info.

Command:

```
/path/to//building_stuff/dmd2/linux/bin64/dmd -O -inline -release -ofwarp cmdline.d constexpr.d context.d directive.d expanded.d file.d id.d lexer.d loc.d macros.d main.d number.d outdeps.d ranges.d skip.d sources.d stringlit.d textbuf.d -v
```

Error excerpt:

```
function  textbuf.Textbuf!char.Textbuf.length
function  textbuf.Textbuf!char.Textbuf.resize
gcc warp.o -o warp -m64 -L/path/to/building_stuff/dmd2/linux/bin64/../lib64 -Xlinker --export-dynamic -l:libphobos2.a -lpthread -lm -lrt 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:libphobos2.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

I was hoping the D language experts here, or those who know about warp already could give me some hint.

I was not on CentOS, as warp demands. I wonder if that could anyway be the reason.
I was not using gcc 4.7.x as warp demands, but, to me, the library could just not be located doesn't look like a problem from old gcc I have.

I was on redhat5.5 machine with 4.1 gcc.

Comment: Maybe your linker (ld) is too old and doesn't support the ```-l:``` syntax? Try to link manually and use ```-lphobos2``` instead of ```-l:libphobos2.a```. (This might link to the shared phobos library. If you want to link statically you'll need to use differen linker commands or simply delete the shared phobos library in dmds lib64 path)

Comment: Yep. I realized as I tried various options. Indeed, it doesn't know about the -l: syntax. Now I'm trying to compiler dmd itself, as the prepacked one from dmd website is dependent on either too new or too old glibc(dnd2.x and dnd1.x) than the default redhat5.5 glibc. thanks

Comment: The compiler is pretty easy to build but notice that it has a weird makefile name: use `make -f posix.mak` instead of plain `make` and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is basically a RedHat, so everything should work OK. As people commented, your real problem is the `-l:libphobos2.a` in your link line. Remember, GNU/Linux allows colons in file-names, so `:libphobos2.a` is a perfectly valid file, and GNU ld won't find it in the library search paths.

Answer (score 0):

Note that they've added a make file to easy on your compilation, I managed to compile it using "make -j" and only editing the dmd command line in the make.

Answer (score 0):

just rename "libphobos2.a" to "lib:libphobos2.a.a"

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with ld version 2.17, but with version 2.20 this 'l:<libfilename>' kinda syntax works fine.